# Dynamic pipe model in MSL, Finite Volume Method

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I'm trying to use Modelica for modeling of a system composed of elastic pipes.
For now, I'm trying to implement my own dynamic pipe model (rigid, not yet elastic) using the same approach (finite volume, staggered) like in the Modelica.Fluid library, but of course not including all the options.

This model should be more simple to understand, as it's a flat model, not extending from other classes. This is important because therefore my colleagues can understand the model even without Modelica Knowhow and I can convince them that Modelica is the adequate tool for our purposes!

As a test case I use a mass flow source with a step signal (waterhammer).
My model gives not the same results like the Modelica.Fluid component.
I would really appreciate, if somebody can help me, understand what's happening!

The **test system** looks like this:

[image: Test system]

The **results for 11 cells** are this:

[image: Results 11 cells]

As you can see, the pressure peak is higher for the MSL component and the frequency/period is not the same. When I chose more cells then the error gets smaller.

I'm quite sure that I'm using exactly the same equations.
Could it be cause of numerical reasons (I tryied using nominal values)?
I also included my own "fixed zeta" flow model for the Modelica.Fluid component so I can compare it in case of a fixed pressure loss coefficient zeta.

The **code of my pipe model** is quite short and it would be really nice if I get it to work like this:

```
model Pipe_FVM_staggered

  // Import
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;

  // Medium
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium "Medium in the component"
    annotation (choicesAllMatching = true);

  // Interfaces, Ports
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_a port_a(redeclare package Medium = Medium) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_b port_b(redeclare package Medium = Medium) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));

  // Parameters
  parameter Integer n(min=2) = 3 "Number of cells"; // No effect yet, only for icon
  parameter SI.Length L = 1 "Length";
  parameter SI.Diameter D = 0.010 "Diameter";
  parameter SI.Height R = 2.5e-5 "Roughness";
  parameter Boolean use_fixed_zeta = false "Use fixed zeta value instead of Moody chart";
  parameter SI.CoefficientOfFriction zeta = 1;

  // Initialization
  parameter Medium.Temperature T_start = 293.15 "Start temperature" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.MassFlowRate mflow_start = 1 "Start mass flow rate in design direction" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_a_start = 2e5 "Start pressure p[1] at design inflow" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_b_start = 1e5 "Start pressure for p[n+1] at design outflow" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  //   parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_start = (p_a_start + p_b_start)/2 annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_start[:] = linspace(p_a_start, p_b_start, n) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  //   parameter Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h_start[:] = Medium.specificEnthalpy_pTX(p_start, T_start, Medium.X_default);
  parameter Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h_start = Medium.specificEnthalpy_pTX((p_a_start + p_b_start)/2, T_start, Medium.X_default) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter SI.AbsolutePressure dp_nominal = 1e5;
  parameter SI.MassFlowRate m_flow_nominal = 1;

  // Variables general
  SI.Length dL = L/n;
  SI.Area A(nominal=0.001) = D^2*pi/4;
  SI.Volume V = A * dL;

  // Variables cell centers: positiv in direction a -> b
  Medium.AbsolutePressure p[n](start = p_start, each stateSelect=StateSelect.prefer) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));
  Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h[n](each start = h_start, each stateSelect=StateSelect.prefer) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));
  Medium.ThermodynamicState state[n] = Medium.setState_phX(p,h);
  SI.Mass m[n] = rho .* V;
  Medium.Density rho[n] = Medium.density(state);
  SI.InternalEnergy U[n] = m .* u;
  Medium.SpecificInternalEnergy u[n] = Medium.specificInternalEnergy(state);
  Medium.Temperature T[n] = Medium.temperature(state);
  Medium.DynamicViscosity mu[n] = Medium.dynamicViscosity(state);
  SI.Velocity v[n](nominal=0.2) = 0.5 * (mflow[1:n] + mflow[2:n+1])  ./ rho ./ A;
  SI.Power Wflow[n];
  SI.MomentumFlux Iflow[n] = v .* v .* rho * A;

  // Variables faces: positiv in direction a -> b
  Medium.MassFlowRate mflow[n+1](each start = mflow_start, each stateSelect=StateSelect.prefer, nominal=0.25) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));
  Medium.EnthalpyFlowRate Hflow[n+1];
  SI.Momentum I[n-1] = mflow[2:n] * dL;
  SI.Force Fp[n-1];
  SI.Force Ff[n-1];
  SI.PressureDifference dpf[n-1](each start = (p_a_start - p_b_start)/(n-1), nominal=0.01e5) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));

equation 

  der(m) = mflow[1:n] - mflow[2:n+1];                    // Mass balance
  der(U) = Hflow[1:n] - Hflow[2:n+1] + Wflow;            // Energy balance
  der(I) = Iflow[1:n-1] - Iflow[2:n] + Fp - Ff;          // Momentum balance, staggered

  Hflow[1] = semiLinear(mflow[1], inStream(port_a.h_outflow), h[1]);
  Hflow[2:n] = semiLinear(mflow[2:n], h[1:n-1], h[2:n]);
  Hflow[n+1] = semiLinear(mflow[n+1], h[n], inStream(port_b.h_outflow));

  Wflow[1] =  v[1] * A .* ( (p[2] - p[1])/2 + dpf[1]/2);
  Wflow[2:n-1] = v[2:n-1] * A .* ( (p[3:n]-p[1:n-2])/2 + (dpf[1:n-2]+dpf[2:n-1])/2);
  Wflow[n] = v[n] * A .* ( (p[n] - p[n-1])/2 + dpf[n-1]/2);

  Fp = A * (p[1:n-1] - p[2:n]);
  Ff = A * dpf; // dpf = Ff ./ A;

  if use_fixed_zeta then
    dpf = 1/2 * zeta/(n-1) * (mflow[2:n]).^2 ./ ( 0.5*(rho[1:n-1] + rho[2:n]) * A * A);
  else
    dpf = homotopy(
      actual = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.WallFriction.Detailed.pressureLoss_m_flow(
        m_flow = mflow[2:n],
        rho_a = rho[1:n-1],
        rho_b = rho[2:n],
        mu_a = mu[1:n-1],
        mu_b = mu[2:n],
        length = dL,
        diameter = D,
        roughness = R,
        m_flow_small = 0.001),
      simplified = dp_nominal/(n-1)/m_flow_nominal*mflow[2:n]);
  end if;

  // Boundary conditions
  mflow[1] = port_a.m_flow;
  mflow[n] = -port_b.m_flow;
  p[1] = port_a.p;
  p[n] = port_b.p;
  port_a.h_outflow = h[1];
  port_b.h_outflow = h[n];

initial equation 
  der(mflow[2:n]) = zeros(n-1);
  der(p) = zeros(n);
  der(h) = zeros(n);

   annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false), graphics={Rectangle(
          extent={{-100,60},{100,-60}},
          fillColor={255,255,255},
          fillPattern=FillPattern.HorizontalCylinder,
          lineColor={0,0,0}),
        Line(
          points={{-100,60},{-100,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{-60,60},{-60,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{-20,60},{-20,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{20,60},{20,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{60,60},{60,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{100,60},{100,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{60,-80},{-60,-80}},
          color={0,128,255},
          visible=showDesignFlowDirection),
        Polygon(
          points={{20,-65},{60,-80},{20,-95},{20,-65}},
          lineColor={0,128,255},
          fillColor={0,128,255},
          fillPattern=FillPattern.Solid,
          visible=showDesignFlowDirection),
        Text(
          extent={{-150,100},{150,60}},
          lineColor={0,0,255},
          textString="%name"),
        Text(
          extent={{-40,22},{40,-18}},
          lineColor={0,0,0},
          textString="n = %n")}),                                Diagram(
        coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
end Pipe_FVM_staggered;
```

I'm struggling with this problem since quite a long time, so any comments or hints are really appreciated!!
If you need some more information or test results, please tell me!

This is the **code for the test example**:

```
model Test_Waterhammer

  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  import g = Modelica.Constants.g_n;

  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT outlet(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1,
    p=2000000,
    T=293.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{70,10}})));

  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(
    allowFlowReversal=true,
    energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial,
    massDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial,
    momentumDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial,
    m_flow_start=0.1,
    m_flow_small=0.0001)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{60,60},{80,80}})));

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T inlet(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1,
    m_flow=0.1,
    use_m_flow_in=true,
    T=293.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-50,-10},{-30,10}})));

  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.TimeTable timeTable(table=[0,0.1; 1,0.1; 1,0.25;
        40,0.25; 40,0.35; 60,0.35])
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-90,10},{-70,30}})));

  Pipe_FVM_staggered                                       pipe(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    R=0.035*0.005,
    mflow_start=0.1,
    L=1000,
    m_flow_nominal=0.1,
    D=0.035,
    zeta=2000,
    n=11,
    use_fixed_zeta=false,
    T_start=293.15,
    p_a_start=2010000,
    p_b_start=2000000,
    dp_nominal=10000)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{10,-10},{30,10}})));

  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipeMSL(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    allowFlowReversal=true,
    length=1000,
    roughness=0.035*0.005,
    m_flow_start=0.1,
    energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial,
    massDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial,
    momentumDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial,
    diameter=0.035,
    modelStructure=Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_vb,
    redeclare model FlowModel =
        Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.FlowModels.DetailedPipeFlow (
          useUpstreamScheme=false, use_Ib_flows=true),
    p_a_start=2010000,
    p_b_start=2000000,
    T_start=293.15,
    nNodes=11)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{10,-50},{30,-30}})));

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T inlet1(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1,
    m_flow=0.1,
    use_m_flow_in=true,
    T=293.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-48,-50},{-28,-30}})));

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT outlet1(
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1,
    p=2000000,
    T=293.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-50},{70,-30}})));


equation 
  connect(inlet.ports[1], pipe.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-30,0},{-10,0},{10,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, outlet.ports[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{30,0},{50,0},{70,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(inlet1.ports[1], pipeMSL.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{-28,-40},{-10,-40},{10,-40}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(pipeMSL.port_b, outlet1.ports[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{30,-40},{50,-40},{70,-40}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(timeTable.y, inlet.m_flow_in)
    annotation (Line(points={{-69,20},{-60,20},{-60,8},{-50,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(inlet1.m_flow_in, inlet.m_flow_in)
    annotation (Line(points={{-48,-32},{-60,-32},{-60,8},{-50,8}}, color={0,0,127}));


  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
        coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)),
    experiment(
      StopTime=15,
      __Dymola_NumberOfIntervals=6000,
      Tolerance=1e-005,
      __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));

end Test_Waterhammer;
```

I've run the **test with 301 cells**:
[image: Results 301 cells]

Zoom peak 1 and 2:
[image: Results 301 cells - peak 1]

[image: Results 301 cells - peak 2]

**Solution: Modifications as suggested by scottG**

```
model FVM_staggered_Ncells

  // Import
  import SI = Modelica.SIunits;
  import Modelica.Constants.pi;

  // Medium
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium "Medium in the component"
    annotation (choicesAllMatching = true);

  // Interfaces, Ports
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_a port_a(redeclare package Medium = Medium) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-10},{-90,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_b port_b(redeclare package Medium = Medium) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));

  // Parameters
  parameter Integer n(min=2) = 3 "Number of cells"; // No effect yet, only for icon
  parameter SI.Length L = 1 "Length";
  parameter SI.Diameter D = 0.010 "Diameter";
  parameter SI.Height R = 2.5e-5 "Roughness";
  parameter Boolean use_fixed_zeta = false "Use fixed zeta value instead of Moody chart";
  parameter SI.CoefficientOfFriction zeta = 1;

  // Initialization
  parameter Medium.Temperature T_start = 293.15 "Start temperature" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.MassFlowRate mflow_start = 1 "Start mass flow rate in design direction" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_a_start = 2e5 "Start pressure p[1] at design inflow" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_b_start = 1e5 "Start pressure for p[n+1] at design outflow" annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_start[:] = linspace(p_a_start, p_b_start, n) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  //   parameter Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h_start[:] = Medium.specificEnthalpy_pTX(p_start, T_start, Medium.X_default);
  parameter Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h_start = Medium.specificEnthalpy_pTX((p_a_start + p_b_start)/2, T_start, Medium.X_default) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization"));
  parameter SI.AbsolutePressure dp_nominal = 1e5;
  parameter SI.MassFlowRate m_flow_nominal = 1;

  // Variables general
  SI.Length dL = L/n;
  SI.Length dLs[n-1] = cat(1,{1.5*dL}, fill(dL,n-3), {1.5*dL});
  SI.Area A = D^2*pi/4;
  SI.Volume V = A * dL;

  // Variables cell centers: positiv in direction a -> b
  Medium.AbsolutePressure p[n](start = p_start, each stateSelect=StateSelect.prefer) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));
  Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h[n](each start = h_start, each stateSelect=StateSelect.prefer) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));
  Medium.ThermodynamicState state[n] = Medium.setState_phX(p,h);
  SI.Mass m[n] = rho .* V;
  Medium.Density rho[n] = Medium.density(state);
  SI.InternalEnergy U[n] = m .* u;
  Medium.SpecificInternalEnergy u[n] = Medium.specificInternalEnergy(state);
  Medium.Temperature T[n] = Medium.temperature(state);
  Medium.DynamicViscosity mu[n] = Medium.dynamicViscosity(state);
  SI.Velocity v[n] = 0.5 * (mflow[1:n] + mflow[2:n+1])  ./ rho ./ A;
  SI.Power Wflow[n];
  SI.MomentumFlux Iflow[n] = v .* v .* rho * A;

  // Variables faces: positiv in direction a -> b
  Medium.MassFlowRate mflow[n+1](each start = mflow_start, each stateSelect=StateSelect.prefer) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));
  Medium.EnthalpyFlowRate Hflow[n+1];
  SI.Momentum I[n-1] = mflow[2:n] .* dLs;
  SI.Force Fp[n-1];
  SI.Force Ff[n-1];
  SI.PressureDifference dpf[n-1](each start = (p_a_start - p_b_start)/(n-1)) annotation(Dialog(tab="Initialization", showStartAttribute=true, enable=false));


equation 

  der(m) = mflow[1:n] - mflow[2:n+1];                    // Mass balance
  der(U) = Hflow[1:n] - Hflow[2:n+1] + Wflow;            // Energy balance
  der(I) = Iflow[1:n-1] - Iflow[2:n] + Fp - Ff;          // Momentum balance, staggered

  Hflow[1] = semiLinear(mflow[1], inStream(port_a.h_outflow), h[1]);
  Hflow[2:n] = semiLinear(mflow[2:n], h[1:n-1], h[2:n]);
  Hflow[n+1] = semiLinear(mflow[n+1], h[n], inStream(port_b.h_outflow));

  Wflow[1] =  v[1] * A .* ( (p[2] - p[1])/2 + dpf[1]/2);
  Wflow[2:n-1] = v[2:n-1] * A .* ( (p[3:n]-p[1:n-2])/2 + (dpf[1:n-2]+dpf[2:n-1])/2);
  Wflow[n] = v[n] * A .* ( (p[n] - p[n-1])/2 + dpf[n-1]/2);

  Fp = A * (p[1:n-1] - p[2:n]);
  Ff = A * dpf;

  if use_fixed_zeta then
    dpf = 0.5 * zeta/(n-1) *  abs(mflow[2:n]) .* mflow[2:n] ./ ( 0.5*(rho[1:n-1] + rho[2:n]) * A * A);
  else
    dpf = homotopy(
      actual = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.WallFriction.Detailed.pressureLoss_m_flow(
        m_flow = mflow[2:n],
        rho_a = 0.5*(rho[1:n-1] + rho[2:n]),
        rho_b = 0.5*(rho[1:n-1] + rho[2:n]),
        mu_a = 0.5*(mu[1:n-1] + mu[2:n]),
        mu_b = 0.5*(mu[1:n-1] + mu[2:n]),
        length = dLs,
        diameter = D,
        roughness = R,
        m_flow_small = 0.001),
      simplified = dp_nominal/(n-1)/m_flow_nominal*mflow[2:n]);
  end if;

  // Boundary conditions
  mflow[1] = port_a.m_flow;
  mflow[n+1] = -port_b.m_flow;
  p[1] = port_a.p;
  p[n] = port_b.p;
  port_a.h_outflow = h[1];
  port_b.h_outflow = h[n];

initial equation 
  der(mflow[2:n]) = zeros(n-1);
  der(p) = zeros(n);
  der(h) = zeros(n);

   annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false), graphics={Rectangle(
          extent={{-100,60},{100,-60}},
          fillColor={255,255,255},
          fillPattern=FillPattern.HorizontalCylinder,
          lineColor={0,0,0}),
        Line(
          points={{-100,60},{-100,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{-60,60},{-60,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{-20,60},{-20,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{20,60},{20,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{60,60},{60,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{100,60},{100,-60}},
          color={0,0,0},
          thickness=0.5),
        Line(
          points={{60,-80},{-60,-80}},
          color={0,128,255},
          visible=showDesignFlowDirection),
        Polygon(
          points={{20,-65},{60,-80},{20,-95},{20,-65}},
          lineColor={0,128,255},
          fillColor={0,128,255},
          fillPattern=FillPattern.Solid,
          visible=showDesignFlowDirection),
        Text(
          extent={{-150,100},{150,60}},
          lineColor={0,0,255},
          textString="%name"),
        Text(
          extent={{-40,22},{40,-18}},
          lineColor={0,0,0},
          textString="n = %n")}),
      Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));

end FVM_staggered_Ncells;
```

**Right result:**
[image]

Comment: Would you be willing to post the code for your example as well?

Comment: Your test/comparison model is a good approach! Maybe you want to add more pipe models, e.g. the pipe from the [LBL Buildings](https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings) library, or from the [Clara library](http://www.claralib.com/) or the [ThermoPower library](https://casella.github.io/ThermoPower/).

Comment: The pipe model from the MSL has many options, I assume you played with these already!? Especially the settings in Advanced->modelStructure and maybe also Assumptions->Dynamics. The MSL pipe model should get more accurate the more elements you use. So if your model gives the same results as the MSL model with e.g. 300 elements, then your model seems to be correct.

Comment: @ScottG
Yes of course! See above, I updated the post.

Comment: @matth
I will test the other libraries you suggested and then add the results here.
Yes, I tested all the settings and tryied to understand the whole model, even if it was a lot of work : /

I added the results for 301 cells above. What do you think?

I would really like to understand why I get this deviation compared to the MSL model, as it seems to me that the problem is of numerical nature. It doesn't seem to be a big error, but it would be nice to understand in order to building up my knowledge...

Comment: @matth
I tried to test the libraries you suggested:

LBL Buildings:
As far as I understood, only the mass & energy balance are discretized, the momentum balance is replaced by a fixed, lumped resistance model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alrighty.. after some digging I figured it out. Below I have shown the "as received" code and then my edit below it. Hopefully this fixes it all.

Background, as you know there is a model structure that is very very important. The one you modeled was `av_vb`.

**1. Correct the length of the flow model**

The variable dL (length of the flow segments) is different for the first and last volume of a `av_vb` model structure. This correction is the most important for the case that was run.

Add the following modification:

```
// Define the variable
SI.Length dLs[n-1];
SI.Momentum I[n-1] = mflow[2:n] .* dLs; // Changed from *dL to .*dLs

// Add to equation section
dLs[1] = dL + 0.5*dL;
dLs[2:n-2] = fill(dL,n-3);
dLs[n-1] =  dL + 0.5*dL;
```

**2. Change from dpf to mflow calculation**

I ran a simple case with a constant flow calculation and checked the results and found they were different even with the first correction. It appears the dpf = f(mflow) calculation was used when under the specified settings the "one-to-one" comparison would be to use mflow=f(dpf). This is because you have chosen `momentumDynamics=SteadyStateInitial` which makes `from_dp = true` in `PartialGenericPipeFlow`. If you change it then the results will be the same for the constant flow example (differences between the two will show up easier since they are not covered up by time dependent dynamics of changing flow rates).

Also, the average densities that were being used differed from the MSL pipe I think. This didn't impact the calculation for this example so feel free to double check my conclusion.

```
  if use_fixed_zeta then
    dpf = 1/2*zeta/(n - 1)*(mflow[2:n]) .^ 2 ./ (0.5*(rho[1:n - 1] + rho[2:n])*
      A*A);
  else

// This was the original
    //      dpf = homotopy(
    //        actual = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.WallFriction.Detailed.pressureLoss_m_flow(
    //          m_flow = mflow[2:n],
    //          rho_a = rho[1:n-1],
    //          rho_b = rho[2:n],
    //          mu_a = mu[1:n-1],
    //          mu_b = mu[2:n],
    //          length = dLs, //Notice changed dL to dLs
    //          diameter = D,
    //          roughness = R,
    //          m_flow_small = 0.001),
    //        simplified = dp_nominal/(n-1)/m_flow_nominal*mflow[2:n]);

// This is the correct model for "one-to-one" comparison for the chosen conditions. Averaged rho and mu was used since useUpstreamScheme = false.
    mflow[2:n] = homotopy(actual=
      Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.WallFriction.Detailed.massFlowRate_dp(
      dpf,
      0.5*(rho[1:n - 1] + rho[2:n]),
      0.5*(rho[1:n - 1] + rho[2:n]),
      0.5*(mu[1:n - 1] + mu[2:n]),
      0.5*(mu[1:n - 1] + mu[2:n]),
      dLs,
      D,
      A,
      R,
      1e-5,
      4000), simplified=m_flow_nominal/dp_nominal .* dpf);
  end if;
```

**3. Correct port_b.m_flow reference**

This is another edit that did not impact the results of this calculation but could in others.

```
// Original
  mflow[n] = -port_b.m_flow;
// Fixed to reference proper flow variable
  mflow[n+1] = -port_b.m_flow;
```

Below is the same plot you generated. The plots overlap.

[image]

Comment: Point 1
Solved the problem!

Point 2
I didn't change dp = f(m_flow) as I got the correct results by following Point1.
In PartialGenericPipeFlow you find
parameter Boolean from_dp = momentumDynamics >= Types.Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial
"= true, use m_flow = f(dp), otherwise dp = f(m_flow)"
As I use steadystate initialization, dp = f(m_flow) should be used.
Did you use SteadyStateInitial?
You're right resp. average densities: The function pressureLoss_m_flow does internally upstream discret.
To do central discr. your modification is needed.

Point 3: thx!

Comment: @T.Sergi: Glad I could help. Regarding `from_dp`. By choosing `momentumDynamics = Dynamics.SteadyStateInitial` (which you did) then `from_dp=true`. Therefore, you should use m_flow = f(dp) but you are using dp = f(m_flow). If you choose DynamicFreeInitial or FixedInitial then `from_dp=false` and you would do dp=f(m_flow). This is because enumerated types are "numbered". DynamicFreeInitial = 1, FixedInitial = 2, SteadyStateInitial = 3, SteadyState = 4. So `from_dp = SteadyStateInitial (3) >= SteadyStateInitial (3)` which is `true`.